# How to define multiple namespace in xml header tag in dwl 2.0 in mulesoft?

Tags: xml, mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb

Success

How to include two namespace in dwl 2.0?

Comment: I solved it using @(xmlns#new:"http://xyz/wsdl/")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean just use two XML namespaces in an XML output?

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
ns orders http://www.acme.com/shemas/Orders
ns stores http://www.acme.com/shemas/Stores
---
root:
    orders#orders: {
        stores#shipNodeId: "SF01",
        stores#shipNodeId @(shipsVia:"LA01"): "NY03"
    }
```

Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<root>
  <orders:orders xmlns:orders="http://www.acme.com/shemas/Orders">
    <stores:shipNodeId xmlns:stores="http://www.acme.com/shemas/Stores">SF01</stores:shipNodeId>
    <stores:shipNodeId xmlns:stores="http://www.acme.com/shemas/Stores" shipsVia="LA01">NY03</stores:shipNodeId>
  </orders:orders>
</root>
```

Taken from the cookbook in the docs: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-cookbook-include-xml-namespaces